# php mysql joining tables with concat

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me with this?
I'm querying from 2 tables, country_table and language_table linked by country_id.

country_table:

```
country_id    continent      country  
 100          asia            china
 101          asia            japan
 102          europe          UK
 103          europe          germany
```

language_table:

```
country_id    language_id     language
 100             01           mandarin  
 100             02           cantonese  
 102             03           english  
 102             04           french
 102             05           welsh
```

What I want to achieved is to display all the countries with or without the language.  If it has language, it should be concatenated just like the sample output below.

```
continent    country    language  
asia          china      mandarin, cantonese  
asia          japan      ----
europe        UK         english, french, welsh
europe        germany    ----
```

Comment: What have tried, young swordfish?

Comment: what i did was i inserted another query(for the language) inside the while loop query for country list, i know its a bad idea, im seeking help in order to correct it.

Comment: Add more information and some code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to do the following:

```
select c.continent,
  c.country,
  group_concat(case 
               when l.language is null 
               then '----' else l.language end order by l.language) language
from country_table c
left join language_table l
  on c.country_id = l.country_id
group by c.continent, c.country
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/955c7/4)

Comment: hi, bluefeet, your answer is working, just a followup question, what would be the selector for the language? sample, $row['']?

Comment: I am not familiar with that syntax. You might want to post another question to get other help.

Comment: i mean, how do i echo the row for the language field?

Comment: @swordfish `$row['language']`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

```
SELECT ct.continent, ct.country, GROUP_CONCAT(lt.language)
FROM country_table ct
LEFT JOIN language_tabel lt USING(country_id)
GROUP BY ct.country
```